# Install docker on windows: impossible to activate virtualization

Tags: docker-for-windows

Hi tried to install docker desktop (3.4.0) on my personal HP laptop (windows 10 home 21h1), but after a successful installation the program continues to crash, raising the exception for a missing enabled virtualization in BIOS.
WSL2 is successfully installed, and I can start an Ubuntu shell.
It seems the only missing part is truly the virtualization from BIOS, which however I was unable to enter so far.
Does anyone know how can I enable virtualization avoiding entering in the BIOS? Shall I overall avoid to enable the virtualization?

Comment: Are you positive you have enabled all of the requirements for Docker for Windows 10 Home?  WSL2 requires hardware virtualization to be enabled in order to function

Comment: I suspect while WSL is working your instance absolutely not a version 2 instance if hardware virtualization isn’t enabled on your machine. Run the following command and provide the output: *wsl --set-default-version 2*